# I am building a simple AI assistant in python but the if statement is not working

Tags: python

I am building a simple AI assistant in python and so far everything has worked pretty well. The voice recognition and text to speech are working also fine. I wanted to make it work like, I am going to speak something and depending on the input it would answer some simple questions. But with the if statement I tried to make conditions depending on the input but it doesn't get executed instead the else statement gets executed.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()
listener = sr.Recognizer()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[2].id)
engine.setProperty("rate", 178)


def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    print(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            print(command)
    except:
        pass
    command = ''
    return command


def run():
    data = command()
    if 'hello' in data:
        talk('Hello')
    elif 'who are you' in data:
        talk('I am an AI.')
    else:
        talk("I couldn't hear it.")


while True:
    run()
```

I have tried to use it without a function but still the same problem. It doesn't work even if the if statement is true.

Comment: `command = ''` … Your command is always empty…

Comment: Well, when I remove the command it throws in a traceback back error. Like UnboundLocalError: local variable 'command' referenced before assignment. That's the issue.

Comment: You might want to start printing the exception you’re getting instead of suppressing it. Might help diagnose why getting the command isn’t working…

Comment: I think you definitely don't want to use the same variable name as a function (`command`). That's going to be extra confusing.

Comment: Well, I also changed the function name but still the same thing.

Comment: You have *two* problems: 1) you’re always overwriting your command with an empty string, and 2) there always seems to be an exception which you’re suppressing.

Comment: Thanks for it, but kindly what can I do to change it?

Comment: Yes, that worked, I removed the command with the empty string but sometimes randomly it still throws in a UnboundLocalError: local variable 'command' referenced before assignment.

Comment: That’s the case where an exception is raised! For the third time: start looking at your exceptions instead of suppressing them silently. I’d start with removing the entire `try..except` block…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wanted to put the `command = ''` in the except block. It is an indentation error.

Comment: Thank you very much, that mostly solved my issue.  At first, I was having a traceback error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'command' referenced before assignment. Now after removing and editing a bit it seems to work fine. Thank you.